# Error using XeLaTeX and Biber to cite sources

Tags: bibliographies, xetex, errors, biber

I am using Biber to cite my sources with `biblatex-apa`, with the package `apa6` on OS X. Everything was going smoothly until I added a certain source which caused `xelatex` to stop compiling with the error:

```
(./test.bbl
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \NewValue.
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.36 ...{Introduction to Neural Networks for {C#}}

?
```

I will provide an MWE that produces the error (to reproduce, run `xelatex test`, `biber test`, then `xelatex test` again):

test.tex

```
\documentclass[man, 12pt]{apa6}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, sorting=nty]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}

\begin{document}
\title{My Title}
\author{My Name}
\affiliation{Chemistry I H, 4th hour, Ms. Kris Clements}
\note{October 15, 2013}
\shorttitle{Algorithms for protein sequence alignment}

\maketitle
Hello world \parencite{heatonresearch}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

test.bib

```
@book{heatonresearch,
    Author = {Heaton, Jeff},
    Publisher = {Heaton Research},
    Title = {Introduction to Neural Networks for {C#}},
    Year = {2008}}
```

A strange thing happens with this setup: If I rerun `biber test`, an error pops up:

```
Entity: line 2063: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document
  <bcf:section number="0">
```

Could someone please explain what the errors mean, and how I can fix this? My paper is due tomorrow, and it's worked fine up until now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It was the pound symbol in the book title, "Introduction to Neural Networks for C#". I didn't know that these symbols have to be escaped using the backslash '\' character.

The corrected test.bib should look like this:

```
@book{heatonresearch,
    Author = {Heaton, Jeff},
    Publisher = {Heaton Research},
    Title = {Introduction to Neural Networks for {C\#}},
    Year = {2008}}
```

Comment: I got the same error, but what was your clue to find out that it was the unescaped `#`?